# Uploading through WebView Issue android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I currently have this webview based android application and my current goal is to be able to upload a image through the webview. However I am in a strange situation at the moment the code I currently have does work when I click the "Debug Button" in Intellij, it runs perfectly when I click the upload button and it displays what applications to select from to upload. But when I Sign the Apk and build it and get it ready for publishing it stops working, so I checked out what error is the app going through and it states:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

So what I done to try and fix it was add the permission that it was requesting in the manifest and that did not work. Here is the code I am currently using to try and upload the file through the webview

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    }
}

 public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                main.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"Image Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated this is the first time I have encountered this error. Also by the way "openFileChooser" is not called upon anywhere else in my application apart from in code above.

Comment: I will start from scratch if I have to with this problem.

Comment: I have noticed that it stopped working after I updated to 4.3 if that helps anyone

Comment: I figured it out the error is occurring due to pro guard, so to fix it I just disabled pro guard when building the app.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it so i can upload with proguard.